# References to generic type SparseArray<E> should be parameterized

Tags: java, android

I tried googling this warning and seem to find others but seems a bit off.

> Type safety: The method put(int, Object) belongs to the raw type
>   SparseArray. References to generic type SparseArray should be
>   parameterized

Can someone explain to me this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SparseArray` works with [Java generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java). Ideally, you should be declaring it as `SparseArray<WhateverYourValueClassIs>` and then storing instances of `WhateverYourValueClassIs` via `put()`.

Comment: SparseArray<Class> sparseArray = new SparseArray<Class>();

sparseArray.put(counter, object) something like this?

Comment: @Akyl: Yes, where `Class` is not `Class`, but an actual Java class representing the base type of what it is that you are storing in the array. This is covered in the Wikipedia page that I linked to in the answer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) and any number of other Java educational resources available online.